# How do I test messenger bot as an admin

Tags: facebook, bots, messenger

I can not test my messenger bot. It says below message if a non-admin sends a message:

> message: '(#10) Cannot message users who are not admins, developers or testers of the app until pages_messaging permission is reviewed and the app is live.

But when I click The send message button, it takes me to edit button.

Fb pages:

[image: fb pages]

Comment: Where are you getting the `user_id` that you're trying to send the message to when you receive that error?

Comment: I did not get any user id. I could not access the user id but I created a test app and it worked.